# Issue in restarting postgres service

Tags: postgresql

I have updated the postgres version to 9.5 (using yum update)

When I try to see the postgres version by :

```
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.23
```

There is postgres service running. I confirmed ut by :

```
systemctl list-unit-files  | grep postg
postgresql.service                            enabled
```

When I try to stop the running postgres service by :

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql.service stop
bash: /etc/init.d/postgresql.service: No such file or directory
```

I tried to start the postgres service gave me same No such file or directory issue.

When I tried to dig into the logs, I found something as below

```
postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 07 16:06:10 punessgdev2 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database 
server.
```

How do I proceed? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: First, please state your OS platform. Looks like you are using a systemd based Linux. Second: "enabled" just states the service _could be started_. Plese, use `systemctl status postgres.service` for a precise answer. Third: you should start/restart a service using `systemctl start _service_` not using any assumptionon where the control file might be located.

Comment: @rpy
I am working on linux platform.  `systemctl status postgres.service` gives me `Unit postgres.service could not be found.`

Comment: Sorry may bad. Should have been `postgresql.service`.

Comment: After hitting `systemctl status postgresql.service`, This is what I got `postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.`

Comment: Then you might try a fresh start: `systemctl start postgresql.service`. Ater that, maybe, `systemctl status postgresql.service` is revealing some more details. Looks like something is broken with the installation. Sorry can't help more on this.

Comment: BTW, did you check all PG packages are at 9.5? At least the server seems to be still at 9.2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and yes PG packages are at 9.5

Comment: Then check whether the `postgres` you did call (giving version 9.2.23) [use `which postgres` for getting the path] is identical to one of the files installed from your PG9.5 packages. Looks like there is some old server left from whatever.

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo systemctl status/start/restart postgresql.service
work fine to me DEBIAN 9 POSTGRES 9.6.15

Comment: Explain it please!